What does the setWaitForStableBoundingBox method do in puppeteer?
Docs do not mention what it actually does and there are no examples how to use it:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.locator.setwaitforstableboundingbox.md
From the name of the method my understanding is, I can somehow use it, to wait for element to have fixed dimensions. But there is no promise to await or no time parameter how often to check if element has stable bounding box.
There is also a similar method for locators called setWaitForEnabled, also without explanation or examples.

The locator API is rather experimental at the moment, and it's not always clear how it works since the documentation isn't fully fleshed out yet. See this section of the locator overview relevant to your question for a brief code example.
setWaitForStableBoundingBox doesn't return a promise because it's a locator configuration call. It toggles a boolean attribute in the locator chain--true or false, whether the locator should wait for a stable bounding box once the locator chain has an action called on it.
Sample usage:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"; // ^22.7.1

const html = `<button onclick="this.textContent = 'clicked'">
</button><script>
const b = document.querySelector("button");
(function update() {
  b.style.height = Math.random() * 40 + "px";
  b.style.width = Math.random() * 40 + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
})();
</script>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.locator("button")
    .setWaitForStableBoundingBox(false) // if true, will time out
    .click();
  console.log(await page.$eval("button", el => el.textContent));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

The sample site has a button with an unstable bounding box. By default, locators will wait for bounding box stability, causing the click to timeout. But if you add .setWaitForStableBoundingBox(false), overriding the default, the click will succeed.
setWaitForEnabled works similarly, but waits for an element (such as an input) to be enabled before taking action:
const html = `<button disabled onclick="this.textContent = 'clicked'">
still disabled
</button><script>
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
}, 3000);
</script>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.locator("button")
    .setWaitForEnabled(false) // if true, will wait before clicking
    .click();
  console.log(await page.$eval("button", el => el.textContent.trim()));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

The default for setWaitForEnabled is true.
See also Understanding Playwright locator Promises. It discusses Playwright, but since Puppeteer has cribbed its locators from Playwright, it should still help clarify how locator promises work for Puppeteer as well. The configuration calls we're discussing are akin to .withRedPaint(), .withFatTires() in the linked example.

I see. Thank you. So in my use case, I could do await page.locator('html').setWaitForStableBoundingBox(true).hover(); to make sure animation stopped before attempting more advanced scenarios like screenshot, and it would wait 100 ms between checks.

That's right, although since true is the default, you can skip the .setWaitForStableBoundingBox(true) call. You only really need it if you're making it false. I'm not sure the delay between checks is offhand but that sounds about right.
